# <script> tag not executed in Handlebars template even with triple braces

Tags: javascript, ember.js, browser, handlebars.js

I am using Ember js to render the main content in my web app. Ember uses Handlebars for templates. The main contest contains html tags and script tags. I have escaped the html tags in my handlebars variable using triple braces. This ensures that html tag in the content is parsed by the browser after the template is rendered. My doubt is that why is the script tag not executed by Javascript parser after the template is rendered. When I inspect via Chrome Inspector, the script tag is present in the content, but not parsed by Javascript. Is there any specific reason for this behavior.

Comment: If the library is injecting the content via the `.innerHTML` of some container element, then the browser will ignore any `<script>` tags; that's just what browsers do. The jQuery API that wraps around `.innerHTML` explicitly finds, extracts, and executes `<script>` content on its own. I don't know what Ember does or if there's a way to request such behavior.

Comment: Thanks Pointy for your answer. I did use the .html() jquery API to test the behavior and it executed the script tag content. I did not verify the innerHTML behavior.

Comment: Can you post the relevant files? What's suppose to trigger the script tag after its executed? Personally, including javascript with a script that in Ember seems all wrong. You should use a component and customize it's component.js to do what you need and simply include the component in the template.

Comment: Sorry @NicholasJohn16, I can't share the code related files here. But here is a jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/rimoca/edit?html,js,output). Here you can see the script tag is not executed. I am just trying to understand why the script tag is not parsed while other html tags are parsed.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason (guess security concerns) why scripts are not executed, but I have a much more important question: What do you try to achieve? Why do you need such (dangerous) feature?

Comment: @GennadyDogaev: It is not a feature I need, but just curiosity that came to my mind. I could not find any answer for the same, so thought of asking here. I am trying to implement a cms feature using ember js.